# Javascript: setTimeout interval seems to be ignored?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the function below which is supposed to run itself every 20ms until a colour fade has completed, but the fade happens instantly - why?

```
function saveColour()
    {
        if(x<=speedms/frameratems)
        {
            currentRed=Math.floor((x*deltaRed)+oldRGB[0]);
            currentGreen=Math.floor((x*deltaGreen)+oldRGB[1]);
            currentBlue=Math.floor((x*deltaBlue)+oldRGB[2]);
            document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor="rgb("+currentRed+", "+currentGreen+", "+currentBlue+")";
            //window.alert("rgb("+currentRed+", "+currentGreen+", "+currentBlue+")");
            x++;
            setTimeout(saveColour(),frameratems);
        }
    }
```

The setTimeout seems to run instantly, no matter what I set frameratems to and I'm not sure why.

Thank you!

Comment: should be setTimeout(saveColour,frameratems); setTimeout expects a reference to a function. saveColour() is invocation, saveColour is reference. you need reference.

Comment: You use wrong syntax: `setTimeout(saveColour(),frameratems);`. It should be: `setTimeout(saveColour,frameratems);`

Comment: for reference, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setTimeout expects a function reference as the first parameter

by calling it with `setTimeout(saveColour(),frameratems);`

you're passing it the return value of `saveColour`

that would be ok if `saveColour` returned a function.

use

```
setTimeout(saveColour,frameratems);
```

instead